# How to pass variable to .conf file via sed command

Tags: variables, sed, httpd.conf, centos7

I am trying to replace some information in my .conf file but the variable **$port** is being passed as a literal string. How can I achieve this using the sed command?

```
 sed -i -e 's/Listen 80/Listen "$port"/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost :D

```
sed -i -e 's/Listen 80/Listen '$port'/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

or

```
sed -i -e "s/Listen 80/Listen $port/g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

More options aside from sed:

HTTPD comes with a specific file for environment variables you can set variables like this, it is called `envvars`, so actually you can have variables in configuration as long as you load that file or any other file with variables you like before starting httpd.

`envvars` is called by the apachectl script that comes with HTTPD too.

Note: Debian for example uses this file extensively and variables inside the server configuration extensively.

---

In 2.4, you can also use the directive `Define` inside the configuration file for httpd, for instance for directives or names you use often in many places of the configuration.

For example:

```
Define sslport 443
```

and then:

```
Listen ${sslport}
<Virtualhost *:${sslport}>
```

So if you need an extensive use of variables you could even mix the two methods, although that may be extreme :)